# AJAX: how to display echoed HTML as it is being generated?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My AJAX request runs a PHP script which calls several functions. Each function queries a different API, generates some HTML based on the results, and populates an array. At the end of the script, the values from the array are added to a database.

Since the functions can take a good chunk of time, I would like my AJAX to display the HTML as it is being generated, i.e. after each function is completed. At the same time, I would like to only have one AJAX request because I need to add all the values to my database at the end.

Hopefully this makes some sense – is what I'm trying to do even possible? Could anyone suggest a solution/workaround/anything to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What have *you* tried so far? Some code you want to share?

Comment: Should be of some interest to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152373/php-flushing-while-loop-data-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server side code doesn't buffer output, and don't wait until the XHR `readyState` has reached `4` before you start making use of `responseText`.