# PHP print string in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function in file `do.php` like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($POST['submit']))
    {
        for($i=0;$i=10;$i++)
        {   
            $reponse = array(
                'content' = > "This is an example - process #" . $i;
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
            sleep(1); // sleep one second each loop
        }
    }
?>
```

and I have some short JQUERY codes use ajax to post data...

```
<button onclick="post()">Submit</button>
function post()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "do.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $('#result').html(json.content);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the output...

```
This is an example - process #1
This is an example - process #2
This is an example - process #3
....
```

When I click on Submit button, I can see a request on [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) run 10 seconds to finish and show the result. Now I want each result showed line by line when it finish in the while loop. I can build a websocket system but this system take very much my times and to big system, I just need a simple way to do this if possible.

I still try to save output in to txt file and use JQUERY read it every 500ms but this way take too much request and it doesn't work well.

Comment: http://php.net/ob_flush  is your friend

Comment: You have a syntax error in your for loop at `$ i=10`, this is an assignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152373/php-flushing-while-loop-data-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve ?
From what I understand you try to execute several processes in SERVER side, and you want, from CLIENT side, to query their status(which process is still running/finished...)
If so, IMO you can execute those processes(using fork() or whatever), and let the parent process to return a list of unique token identifier for each process, to your AJAX request.
Now for every 500ms, using **setInterval()**, query the of the tokens your received.

Hope it help a bit.